# Scan QR code and pass the value to a field in ReactJS page with iPad

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, ipad, qr-code

I have created a ReactJS page which has a text field run on Chrome on desktop. The text field content is inputted by scanning a QR code of product by a barcode scanner.

Now I would like to run this page with iPad. As the iPad camera is able to decode barcode content, I would like to use the iPad camera to scan the QR code and pass the content to that text field.

I think the screen flow should be:

1. Cursor focus on the text field
2. iPad camera switch on
3. User can scan the QR code
4. QR code content fill in that text field

Does anyone has experience for this use case? Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried some library such as React-qr-reader, Quaggajs, and some git source such as https://github.com/Minishlink/pwa-qr-code-scanner/blob/master/app/index.html, but i can't make the flow like what I have proposed